# Amend Query To Check For Multiple Values Within A Group Based On Specific Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table from an external system (data is anonymised):

[image]

I use the following query to group the results by the combination of columns `cola`, `colb` and `colc`; and the case statements replaces the x values in the weekday columns with the corresponding value in the `amount` column. This works well.

```
SELECT
cola, 
colb, 
colc,
max(case when Mon = 'x' THEN amount END) as Mon,
max(case when Tue = 'x' THEN amount END) as Tue,
max(case when Wed = 'x' THEN amount END) as Wed,
max(case when Thu = 'x' THEN amount END) as Thu,
max(case when Fri = 'x' THEN amount END) as Fri,
max(case when Sat = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sat,
max(case when Sun = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sun
FROM tbltestquote
GROUP BY
cola, 
colb, 
colc
```

And the result is:

[image]

I have now added a new column called `threshold`. You can see that when grouping by `cola`, `colb` and `colc`, there can be more than one value for `threshold`, as shown below:

[image]

My updated SQL query to take this new column into account is this:

```
SELECT 
cola, 
colb, 
colc,
threshold,
max(case when Mon = 'x' THEN amount END) as Mon,
max(case when Tue = 'x' THEN amount END) as Tue,
max(case when Wed = 'x' THEN amount END) as Wed,
max(case when Thu = 'x' THEN amount END) as Thu,
max(case when Fri = 'x' THEN amount END) as Fri,
max(case when Sat = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sat,
max(case when Sun = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sun
FROM tbltestquote
GROUP BY
cola, 
colb, 
colc,
threshold
```

And that returns the following results set with the two new rows, which is correct:

[image]

I now want to add a new boolean column that indicates if there are multiple threshold values when grouping by `cola`, `colb` and `colc`, as per the mockup result set below:

[image]

Notice that the `hasMultipleThreshold` column is TRUE for all rows where the `cola`, `colb` and `colc` group has a second threshold value, not just simply the one different row.

I am unsure how to modify my query for this column, if it is indeed possible. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT 
cola, 
colb, 
colc,
threshold,
max(case when Mon = 'x' THEN amount END) as Mon,
max(case when Tue = 'x' THEN amount END) as Tue,
max(case when Wed = 'x' THEN amount END) as Wed,
max(case when Thu = 'x' THEN amount END) as Thu,
max(case when Fri = 'x' THEN amount END) as Fri,
max(case when Sat = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sat,
max(case when Sun = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sun,
case when count(*) over(partition by cola,colb,colc order by cola)>1 then 1 else 0 end as hasMultipleThreshold 
FROM tbltestquote a
GROUP BY
cola, 
colb, 
colc,
threshold
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the following error `Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.`

Comment: @JohnSteed, I've changed it you can check now

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
SELECT 
cola, 
colb, 
colc,
threshold,
max(case when Mon = 'x' THEN amount END) as Mon,
max(case when Tue = 'x' THEN amount END) as Tue,
max(case when Wed = 'x' THEN amount END) as Wed,
max(case when Thu = 'x' THEN amount END) as Thu,
max(case when Fri = 'x' THEN amount END) as Fri,
max(case when Sat = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sat,
max(case when Sun = 'x' THEN amount END) as Sun,
( select case 
        when count(threshold)>0 
            then cast(1 as bit) 
        else 
            cast(0 as bit) 
        end 
  from tbltestquote as ts where ts.cola=t.cola and ts.colb=t.colb and ts.colc= t.colc 
   group by ts.cola, ts.colb, ts.colc, ts.threshold ) as hasMultipleThreshold 
FROM tbltestquote as t
GROUP BY
cola, 
colb, 
colc,
threshold
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the following error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.`